# Save inserted rows in TableView after reload and etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have simple tableView with some items. After clicking on item I am going in to specific tableview for this items. Which one contains some data. Also in second table view I can add rows.

The problem is then I added some rows and coming back to first tableView or shutdowning app and launching again rows are not saved. Here is code of second tableView(in second section first row are fixed):

```
@interface CurrentDeviceTableViewController ()

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger stepsCount;

@end

@implementation CurrentDeviceTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _stepsCount=0;

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FixedCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FixedCell"];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FullInfo" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FullInfo"];

   // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                                                                 target:self
                                                                                 action:@selector(addEvent:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section==0)
        return 1;
    else if(section==1)
        return _stepsCount+1;

    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    StepsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Steps" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.section==0){
            if(indexPath.row==0){
                    FullInfoTableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FullInfo" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    return cell;
            }
    }

    if(indexPath.section==1){
            if(indexPath.row==0){
                FixedCell *cell = (FixedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FixedCell"];
                [cell layoutIfNeeded];
                return cell;
        }else{
            StepsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Steps" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            return cell;

        }
    }

    return cell;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section==1)
    return @"Second";

    return nil;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 70;
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 100;
    }
    return 35;
}

-(IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_stepsCount+1 inSection:1];
    NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path,nil];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
     _stepsCount+=1;
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];


    NSLog(@"qw3d%li",(long)_stepsCount);
}

@end
```

Comment: Well data jusy does not save it self. You have to do this.

Comment: You can save Your DataSource in NSUserDefaults or SQLite.

Comment: you mean you want to save the selected data by tapping on tableview and loads again after app terminates?